Different headers in .DOCX using ReportBuilder
I want to make different headers for my report from report builder. When I download report as PDF it shows me different headers for it, when I download it as .DOCX, the headers are the same.
I tried:
Adding two headers with different body and using: =IIf(Globals!PageNumber = 1, False, True) 
I have tried the same header and using expressions: =IIf(Globals!PageNumber = 1, First(Fields!Contacts.Value, "dataset"), "")
None of that works for .DOCX.

Yeah. I also found this: Microsoft
It says that exporting to PDF is using Hard Page-break while exporting to DOCX is Soft Page-break for readability purposes. It is possible that this may be the problem too.
